# Como Activar un método que esta en otro activity a traves de un Intent en un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Lo que tengo : Un RecyclerView con imágenes que cuando le das click te lleva a un mapa con tu ubicación actual.

Lo que quiero : Quiero activar mediante un Intent un metodo que se encuentra en otro activity mediante un evento de click dentro de mi RecyclerView, el cuál está en otro Activity, con el objetivo que me muestre la info que dentro de este metodo se ejecuta.

Mi pregunta : Cómo puedo llevar a cabo dicha petición. Por favor, agradecería las respuestas con ejemplos de código puesto que aún no soy muy bueno programando, gracias de antemano

Desde donde quiero activar dicho método

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.etiNombre.setText(listalugares.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());

        holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listalugares.size();
    }
}
```

El método que quiero activar

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,

 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {//este es el método que quiero llamar
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

//        Button btnRestaurant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRestaurant);//asi se hace la peticion
//        btnRestaurant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            String Restaurant = "restaurant";
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
//                mMap.clear();
//                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
//                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
//                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
//                DataTransfer[1] = url;
//                Log.d("onClick", url);
//                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
//                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
//                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            }
//        });
```

Comment: el `onReady()` se llama automaticamente al instanciar tu fragmente, llamas el `getMapAsync()`

Comment: Seria tan amable de ponerme un ejemplo de código, es que aún no se como hacerlo :( , muchas gracias por u respuesta

Comment: @JuanAntonioSánchezJiménez solo envía un valor en el intent y lo lees  al recibirlo en la Activity, dependiendo del valor llamas o no el método, agregué un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar dentro de tu lista enlazada las coordenadas que pertenecen a esa imagen, por ejemplo

Crear lista;

```
listalugares ArrayList<list> = null
listalugares.add(new list(R.id.foto_1,"nombre", 8.3265132,9.326541))
```

Consultar lista;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("latidude", listalugares.get(position).getlatitude);
        i.putExtra("longitude", listalugares.get(position).getlongitude);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

También puedes usar Event Bus una [librería](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) para pasar información entre clases.

Comment: Este ejemplo solo envía datos de un ArrayList en un Intent, debe llamar un método de acuerdo a lo que indica el OP.

Comment: @Jorgesys Cuando se crear una lista usando RecyclerView
 es necesario generar un ArrayList con los datos que se quieren mostrar, por lo tanto ademas de enviar las imágenes como indica el ejemplo también se pueden enviar las coordenadas, así al dar clic a la imagen se busca en el ArrayList con el indice que genera el clic (int position)y se busca las coordenadas que están almacenada en ese ArrayList, de eso modo el dato solicitado y se envía en el PutExtra y envia a la nueva actividad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo que quiere decir el ejemplo es que se puede agregar al modelo listalugares las coordenadas y cuando el usuario le clic se obtiene el indice para entonces consultar al ArrayList las coordenadas  que se almacenarlos en la lista y así enviarla con putExtra a la siguiente actividad.

Comment: "con el objetivo que me muestre la info que dentro de este metodo se ejecuta." , el método es onMapReady() pero además este método no puede ser llamado manualmente, es llamado cuando se carga correctamente el mapa. @LordSaac

Answer (score 0):

En tu `Intent` envía una propiedad que determine llamar el método:

```
holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("call_method", true); // *Envia valor!
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
```

en el método `onCreate()` recibes y lees el valor de la propiedad, en este caso si el valor es `true` llamas el método:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean callMethod = extras.getBoolean("call_method");

if(callMethod) {
    //Llama método en Activity abierta mediante Intent.
}
```

En el sitio en inglés existe una pregunta similar:

[Como llamar un método usando un Intent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946171/how-to-call-a-method-using-intent?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

---

**En cuanto al método [onMapReady()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)) hay un mal entendido, este método no lo puedes llamar tu, este método se llama cuando la instancia de tu mapa se carga correctamente. Tu no puedes determinar el llamado de este método.**